# allocating a bytes list in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have 2 files which I am reading as bytes, I have another hardcoded 64 bytes array which I need to manipulate later.

```
 temp_list = []
    open_file_to_list(file_name1, temp_list)
    open_file_to_list(file_name2, temp_list)
    for byte_i in harcoded_arr: #byte_i is really an int
        temp_list.append(byte_i)
```

In order to create the hardcoded array I used bytearray but when I iterate over it, it is iterates as integers and not as bytes.

I would like to append the byte array as bytes to the list.

```
  harcoded_arr= bytearray(64)
  harcoded_arr[61] = 1
  harcoded_arr[62] = 1
  harcoded_arr[63] = 1
```

How can I iterate it the bytearray as bytes using Python 3.8

Comment: Do you want  `harcoded_arr[63] = 1` as `bytearray(b'\x01')`?

Comment: @toRex yes that one as well. But I want the entire array as list of bytes. Added to the other list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice the bytes object to get 1-length bytes objects

```
harcoded_arr = bytearray(64)
harcoded_arr[61] = 1
harcoded_arr[62] = 1
harcoded_arr[63] = 1

for i in range(len(harcoded_arr)):
    print(harcoded_arr[i:i+1])
```

**Output**

```
bytearray(b'\x00')
bytearray(b'\x00')
bytearray(b'\x00')
.................
bytearray(b'\x01')
bytearray(b'\x01')
bytearray(b'\x01')
```

**PEP-467** proposes that bytes and bytearray gain an optimized iterbytes method that produces length 1 bytes objects rather than integers

```
>>> tuple(b"ABC".iterbytes())
(b'A', b'B', b'C')
```

For more you can also go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267452/iterate-over-individual-bytes-in-python-3)