# Python 3: for x in bytes as words

Tags: python-3.x, binary-data

I have a python3 script which reads data into a buffer with

```
fp = open("filename", 'rb')
data = fp.read(count)
```

I don't fully understand (even after reading the documentation) what `read()` returns. It appears to be some kind of binary data which is iterable. But it is not a list.

Confusingly, elsewhere in the script, lists are used for binary data.

```
frames = []
# then later... inside a loop
for ...
    data = b''.join(frames)
```

Regardless... I want to iterate over the object returned by `read()` in units of word (aka 2 byte blocks)

At the moment the script contains this for loop

```
for c in data:
    # do something
```

Is it possible to change `c` such that this loop iterates over words (2 byte blocks) rather than individual bytes?

I cannot use `read()` in a loop to read 2 bytes at a time.

Comment: "I don't fully understand (even after reading the documentation) what read() returns. It appears to be some kind of binary data which is iterable. But it is not a list." Was [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the documentation you found? It says right there, `Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument) return contents as bytes objects without any decoding`, and the word `bytes` is linked to the documentation for that type.

Comment: "Confusingly, elsewhere in the script, lists are used for binary data." *A* list is used, which presumably contains `bytes` objects that are concatenated using the `join` method of `b''` (another `bytes` object).

Comment: What type of object do you expect `c` to be? In its current form, `c` would be an `int`. However in "2 byte blocks" it would be a `bytes` object.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That appears to be the documentation for `open()`? Not `read()`.

Comment: Yes, it's the documentation for `open()`. `open()` is how you create file objects, and the documentation there explains what you can do with those. `.read()` is a method of file objects, so that's where you get the appropriate documentation.

Comment: You could also click through the link to [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files) from the official Python tutorial, which explains: `'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects. This mode should be used for all files that don’t contain text.`

Answer (score 1):

We can explicitly read (up to) `n` bytes from a file in binary mode with `.read(n)` (just as it would read `n` Unicode code points from a file opened in text mode). This is a blocking call and will only read fewer bytes at the end of the file.

We can use the two-argument form of `iter` to build an iterator that repeatedly calls a callable:

```
>>> help(iter)
Help on built-in function iter in module builtins:

iter(...)
    iter(iterable) -> iterator
    iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator

    Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
    supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
    In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
```

`read` at the end of the file will start returning empty results and not raise an exception, so we can use that for our sentinel.

Putting it together, we get:

```
for pair in iter(lambda: fp.read(2), b''):
```

Inside the loop, we will get `bytes` objects that represent two bytes of data. You should check the documentation to understand how to work with these.

Answer (score 1):

When reading a file in binary mode, a `bytes` object is returned, which is one of the standard python builtins. In general, its representation in the code looks like that of a string, except that it is prefixed as `b"   "` - When you try printing it, each byte may be displayed with an escape like `\x**` where `**` are 2 hex digits corresponding to the byte's value from 0 to 255, or directly as a single printable ascii character, with the same ascii codepoint as the number. You can read more about this and methods etc of bytes (also similar to those for strings) [in the `bytes` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects).

There already seems to be [a very popular question on stack overflow about how to iterate over a bytes object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267452/iterate-over-individual-bytes-in-python-3). The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267935) gives this example for creating a `list` of individual bytes in the `bytes` object :

```py
L = [bytes_obj[i:i+1] for i in range(len(bytes_obj))]
```

I suppose that modifying it like this will work for you :

```py
L = [bytes_obj[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(bytes_obj), 2)]
```

For example :

```py
by = b"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06" 
# The object returned by file.read() is also bytes, like the one above
words = [by[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(by), 2)]
print(words)
# Output --> [b'\x00\x01', b'\x02\x03', b'\x04\x05', b'\x06']
```

Or create a generator that yields words in the same way if your list is likely to be too large to efficiently store at once:

```py
def get_words(bytesobject):
    for i in range(0, len(bytesobject), 2):
        yield bytesobject[i:i+2]
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this is pretty useful. It seems like I'm actually asking the wrong question. Perhaps I should have asked, "why does iterating over bytes object return `int`s"

Comment: "Perhaps I should have asked, "why does iterating over bytes object return ints" Because a `bytes` object represents a sequence of bytes *of memory*, and the simplest way to interpret an 8-bit value is as an 8-bit unsigned integer? Seems about right to me. Certainly I have found it useful in the past. I'm not sure what else you expected; it's not a string type (in 3.x; and the 2.x design was frankly quite flawed).

Answer (score 0):

In the most simple literal sense, something like this gives you a two byte at a time loop.

```
with open("/etc/passwd", "rb") as f:
    w = f.read(2)
    while len(w) > 0:
        print( w  )
        w = f.read(2)
```

as for what you are getting from `read`, it's a `bytes` object, because you have specified 'b' as an option to the `open

I think a more python way to express it would be via an iterator or generator.